# POST request using Alamofire.request and URLRequestConvertible

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, alamofire

Below is the code of my URLRequestConvertible

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://example.com/"

    case LoginRequest(String, String)
    case SignUpRequest(String)
    case ForgotPasswordRequest(String)

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

        let result: (path: String, method: Method, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
            switch self {
            case .LoginRequest(let userName, let password):
                let params = [userNameKey: userName, passwordKey: password]
                return ("/AppUsers/login", .POST, params)
            case .SignUpRequest(let profile):
                let params = [fullNameKey: profile]
                return ("/AppUsers/add", .POST, params)
            case .ForgotPasswordRequest(let emailId):
                let params = [userNameKey: emailId]
                return ("/AppUsers/forgot_password", .POST, params)
            }
        }()

        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result.path))
        let encoding = ParameterEncoding.URL

        request.URLRequest.HTTPMethod = result.method.rawValue
        return encoding.encode(request, parameters: result.parameters).0
    }
}
```

Now, I have below request which is working fine:

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, CommunicationService.Router.LoginRequest(txtUsername.text!, txtPassword.text!).URLRequest, parameters: ["email_id": txtUsername.text!, "password": txtPassword.text!], encoding: ParameterEncoding.JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) { (response) -> Void in
        print(response)
    }
```

But I want to make the use of URLRequestConvertible for Parameter passing for POST request. Let me know what is the best way for POST request using below API:

```
 request(.POST, CommunicationService.Router.LoginRequest(txtUsername.text!, txtPassword.text!).URLRequest).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
        print(response)
        })
```

Actually, above code is giving Invalid response with below error message

**FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}**

What's wrong with the request generated using request(Method, URLStringConvertible) method?

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the other form of the `request` method.

```
let loginRequest = CommunicationService.Router.LoginRequest(username,  password).URLRequest

Alamofire.request(loginRequest).responseJSON { in
    print(response)
}
```

Otherwise you are only using the URLString from the original `NSURLRequest` being created by the `Router`.